# compare aws EC2 g3 instances with gtx 1070 or 1080 Ti

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, blender

I am new to the GPU computing and cloud computing. I am wondering if you can directly compare the aws [g3 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-next-generation-gpu-powered-ec2-instances-g3/) with gtx 1070 or gtx 1080 Ti graphic card in terms of performance. (price aside)

My current project is a blender 2500-frame 3D animation. (1 to 2 minutes to render each frame in g3.4xlarge instance)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The g3 instances use NVIDIA Tesla M60 GPUs, which actually has 2 GPU's vs the 1080's one (I am using that since it is the faster one)

1080 has 2560 cores whereas the Tesla has 4096 cores (2048 per core)
1080 has 8GB RAM vs 16GB for the Tesla (8 per core)

Based on just those specs, id say the Tesla's will come out on top. You can compare them yourself with the below links:

Tesla: http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-m60.html
GTX 1080: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1080/